# Error at creating word cloud in R (Error in simple_triplet_matrix: 'i, j, v' different lengths)

Tags: r, text-processing, tm, word-cloud

I have the following code in R to get the recent tweets about the local mayor candidates and create a wordcloud:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
require(RCurl)
library(stringr)
library(tm)
library(ggmap)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)
(...)
setup_twitter_oauth(...)
N = 10000 #Number of twetts
S = 200 #200Km radius from Natal (Covers the whole Natal area)
candidate = 'Carlos+Eduardo'

#Lists so I can add more cities in future codes
lats = c(-5.7792569)
lons = c(-35.200916)

# Gets the tweets from every city
result = do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      1:length(lats),
      function(i) searchTwitter(
          candidate,
          lang="pt-br",
          n=N,
          resultType="recent",
          geocode=paste(lats[i], lons[i], paste0(S,"km"), sep=",")
      )
    )
  )

# Get the latitude and longitude of each tweet,
# the tweet itself, how many times it was re-twitted and favorited,
# the date and time it was twitted, etc and builds a data frame.

result_lat = sapply(result, function(x) as.numeric(x$getLatitude()))
result_lat = sapply(result_lat, function(z) ifelse(length(z) != 0, z, NA))

result_lon = sapply(result, function(x) as.numeric(x$getLongitude()))
result_lon = sapply(result_lon, function(z) ifelse(length(z) != 0, z, NA))

result_date = lapply(result, function(x) x$getCreated())
result_date = sapply(result_date,
    function(x) strftime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M%S", tz="UTC")
  )

result_text = sapply(result, function(x) x$getText())
result_text = unlist(result_text)

is_retweet = sapply(result, function(x) x$getIsRetweet())

retweeted = sapply(result, function(x) x$getRetweeted())

retweet_count = sapply(result, function(x) x$getRetweetCount())

favorite_count = sapply(result, function(x) x$getFavoriteCount())

favorited = sapply(result, function(x) x$getFavorited())

tweets = data.frame(
    cbind(
        tweet = result_text,
        date = result_date,
        lat = result_lat,
        lon = result_lon,
        is_retweet=is_retweet,
        retweeted = retweeted,
        retweet_count = retweet_count,
        favorite_count = favorite_count,
        favorited = favorited
      )
  )

# World Cloud

#Text stemming require the package ‘SnowballC’.
#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SnowballC/index.html

#Create corpus
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(tweets$tweet))

corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)

corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('portuguese'))

corpus = tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)

wordcloud(corpus, max.words = 50, random.order = FALSE)
```

But I'm getting these errors:

> Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow =
>   length(allTerms),  :
>
> 'i, j, v' different lengths
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params,
>   retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
>
> 10000 tweets were requested but the API can only return 518
>     #I understant this one, I cannot get more tweets that exists
>
> 2: In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :   all
>   scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
>
> 3: In simple_triplet_matrix(i = i, j = j, v = as.numeric(v), nrow =
>   length(allTerms),  :   NAs introduced by coercion

It's my first time building a wordcloud and I followed tutorials like this [one](https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-wordclouds-in-r/).

It's there a way to fix it? Another things is: the class of `tweets$tweet` is "factor", should I convert it or something? If yes, how I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this [tutorial](http://thinktostart.com/create-a-wordcloud-with-your-twitter-data/) where it's defined a function to "clean" the text and also creating a TermDocumentMatrix instead of a stemDocument before building the wordcloud. It's working properly now.

[image: My wordcloud]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `wordcloud` is not defined for **tm** corpus objects.  Install the **quanteda** package, and try this:

```
plot(quanteda::corpus(corpus), max.words = 50, random.order = FALSE)
```

Comment: I will try it soon @Ken, Thank you.