# I can't create a cloud with this algoritm

Tags: r, data-science, word-cloud

I'm trying to run this code to create a wordcloud that I saw in the class. But I cannot find the solving problem by the error that appears where I try plot the wordcloud. the error is: Error in wordcloud(dfCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE) :
it was not possible find the function "wordcloud". Can anyone help?

```
install.packages("tm", "SnowballC", "worldcloud", "RColorBrewer")
library(tm, SnowballC,worldcloud,RColorBrewer)

df <- read.csv('C:/r_fundamentos/parte2/questoes.csv', sep = ",")
head(df)

dfCorpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(df$Question))
class(dfCorpus)
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus,removePunctuation)
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus, stemDocument)
dfCorpus <- tm_map(dfCorpus, removeWords, c("the", "this", c(stopwords("english"))))
wordcloud(dfCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE)
```

Comment: Misspelling of “wordcloud”.

Answer (score 0):

I think he does not load all the packages. Try instead:

library(tm) ; library(SnowballC) ; library(worldcloud) ; library(RColorBrewer)

Comment: another error: Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 'i, j' invalid

Comment: This might come from your data. could you provide an example of your data?

This previous posts could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334697/new-error-being-thrown-with-tm-package-and-dtm-wordclouds

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668845/error-at-creating-word-cloud-in-r-error-in-simple-triplet-matrix-i-j-v-dif

Comment: Why are you copying his misspelling of “wordcloud”?